# How can I set custom voice command with Google Assistant that wake my app?

Tags: android, voice-recognition, receiver, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I want to set *custom voice command* for my app. For example if my app name is `apple` I want to wake my app by saying *apple*. Or something like `apple turn of the lamp`.
Does android have something like that? If not can I use a receiver to detect voice commands and wait for `apple` voice? For voice detection use Google Voice detection.

Thanks.